# Newly installed Debian install is not recognized

Tags: debian, boot

I recently formatted an entire drive so I could install Linux on it. The partitions:

```
15 GB, Primary, sda1, mount point: /
232.9 GB Logical, sda5, mount point: /home
3 GB Logical, sda6, swap
```

However, upon install completion (with the GRUB bootloader) and reboot, the BIOS reports that it cannot find a bootable device.

<s>I am thinking that I did not set sda1's `bootable` flag. If this is the case - is there some way I can do this from the Debian CD's "rescue mode"?</s>

The exact error message from the BIOS is `No bootable device -- insert boot disk and press any key`.

*Attempted*:

- Removed all other boot options (CD, USB) from the boot list
- Swapped cabled
- Tried other SATA ports
- Swapped hard drives (with new SSD)

Comment: The bootable flag isn't read by the BIOS, it's read by some bootloaders (but not the ones most commonly used for Linux). What bootloader did you install? What's the exact error message from the BIOS? And yes, this is likely to be fixable from the CD, look for a way to repair Grub (I think there's a menu entry for that).

Comment: Thanks for the comment Gilles - I've added the message I received.

Comment: Do you have multiple disks? Is that an internal disk or an external one (e.g. USB)?

Comment: I am installing to an internal SATA Hard Drive via an ISO burned to a CD. I have tried booting into rescue mode and running grub-install /dev/sda, which did nothing. There were no errors (that I could see) during installation.

Comment: Upon booting into a rescue shell and inspecting the file structure, I can see that the files all exist, so as far as I can tell, the hard drive is not at fault here.

Comment: Check the boot order in the bios. Is your disk there?

Comment: Hello Faheem - indeed, the Hard Drive is detected properly, and was moved (by myself) to the top of the list.

Comment: Gilles - apparently, the bootable flag was the problem... which is interesting, because I swear I flagged it last time. In any case, you can submit your answer for acceptance below.

Answer (score 1):

I am posting here Gilles answer :

> The bootable flag isn't read by the BIOS, it's read by some
>   bootloaders (but not the ones most commonly used for Linux). [...] And yes, this is likely to be fixable from the CD, look for a
>   way to repair Grub (I think there's a menu entry for that).

Answer (score 0):

I would disable everything booting except the harddrive and see if you can boot it. If you really can't boot from it, boot in live and run a diagnostic on the drive with smarttools. You can usually get away with a short test (takes about two minutes).

Comment: Disabling everything except the Hard Drive didn't change anything. It seems as though that particular message comes up when it has exhausted all boot options.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install `grub` to `/dev/sda1` or to `/dev/sda`? It should be `/dev/sda`.

Comment: Whichever debian defaulted to (which would probably be /dev/sda). I also tried booting into the CD's rescue mode, and ran `install-grub /dev/sda`, but to no avail. I also purchased a new hard drive, so the drive is not at fault here. Perhaps the cable or the SATA controller...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that particular message comes up when it has exhausted all boot options.

By chance, may it be that you disabled other boot option, but your hard drive is not the first option and there is some BIOS option to only try one (first) option? I've seen such configurations before.